# Realm .NET Where query with Contains() throws System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, realm

I'm using Realm for .NET v10.1.3, and I've got a method that deletes some objects. Pulling from the documentation that indicates that Contains is supported, I have the following snippet:

```
var results = realm.All<DeviceEventEntity>()
    .Where(entity => ids.Contains(entity.Id));
                            
realm.RemoveRange(results);
```

But when `realm.RemoveRange(results)` is executed, Realm throws a System.NotSupportedException. What am I doing wrong here? Or does Realm not support Contains?

Here's the stacktrace:

```
System.NotSupportedException
The method 'Contains' is not supported
   at Realms.RealmResultsVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) in C:\jenkins\workspace\realm_realm-dotnet_PR-2362@2\Realm\Realm\Linq\RealmResultsVisitor.cs:line 378
   at Realms.RealmResultsVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) in C:\jenkins\workspace\realm_realm-dotnet_PR-2362@2\Realm\Realm\Linq\RealmResultsVisitor.cs:line 164
   at Realms.RealmResults`1.CreateHandle() in C:\jenkins\workspace\realm_realm-dotnet_PR-2362@2\Realm\Realm\Linq\RealmResults.cs:line 65
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at Realms.RealmResults`1.get_ResultsHandle() in C:\jenkins\workspace\realm_realm-dotnet_PR-2362@2\Realm\Realm\Linq\RealmResults.cs:line 30
   at Realms.Realm.RemoveRange[T](IQueryable`1 range) in C:\jenkins\workspace\realm_realm-dotnet_PR-2362@2\Realm\Realm\Realm.cs:line 1279
   at DocLink.Client.Storage.Service.Event.DeviceEventService.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<DeleteEvents>b__0() in
```

Here's a more complete example:

```
public Task DeleteEvents(List<ObjectId> ids) {
  return Task.Run(() => {
    using (var realm = GetRealm()) {
      using (var transaction = realm.BeginWrite()) {
        try {
          var results = realm.All<DeviceEventEntity>().Where(entity => ids.Contains(entity.Id));
          realm.RemoveRange(results);
          transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
          transaction.Rollback();
          throw new ServiceException("Unable to delete events. Transaction has been rolled back.", exception);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Also, it seems a little odd that the library is referencing files like this `C:\jenkins\workspace\realm_realm-dotnet_PR-2362@2\Realm\Realm\Linq\RealmResultsVisitor.cs`. This is not anything that's on my system, the library is pulled in through NuGet.

Comment: `Or does Realm not support Contains?` Correct. https://www.google.com/search?q=realm+linq+contains+support

Comment: This is a little frustrating, because Mongo specifically shows this example in their online documentation:

**Debug.WriteLine("Ali or Jamie's tasks: "
    + tasks.Where(t => new List<string> { "Ali", "Jamie" }.Contains(t.Assignee)));**

[Filter On Object Properties](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/examples/read-and-write-data/#filter-queries-based-on-object-properties)

Comment: Where are those docs @TravisBeech?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/examples/read-and-write-data/#filter-queries-based-on-object-properties

Comment: Please share a [mcve] including how `ids` is populated.

Comment: @mjwills Edited original question with the full method. There's not a whole lot there, the list is a standard List<ObjectId>.

Comment: Does it work if the `Contains` is on a string property like in the docs?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009005/query-realm-for-objects-by-ids-collection work for you?

Comment: Haven't tried on a string property, even if that works, my primary key in document is an ObjectId. The work around for now is ToList() the original query, then perform the 'where contains' operation. The only downside is I can't use the RemoveRange() method, I have to loop over the results and delete them one at a time. So that's not the most ideal solution. It looks like the Filter() method will work, but I'm stuck waiting on the next minor release of 10.2 for that support.

Comment: I'll give that one a closer look. I came across it once tonight, and it reminded me of a solution I had to use in Realm for Obj-C a long time ago.

Comment: `Haven't tried on a string property, even if that works, my primary key in document is an ObjectId.` I know. But it helps to narrow down where the problem is. For example you state the docs are wrong. Well, we don't actually know that yet - since your test is different to the docs.

Comment: @TravisBeech the linked answer shows how to construct multiple `OR` conditions and `Filter`, not how to work with string properties. Relational database providers map `Enumerable.Contains(someField)` to `someField in (value1,value2,value3,.....)`. That's equivalent to `someField=value1 OR someField=value2 OR ....`. Even in relational databases, a *LOT* of the time it's easier to use SQL directly or through Dapper than use LINQ

Comment: @TravisBeech another option could be to use [LinqKit's PredicateBuilder](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#using-predicatebuilder) to construct the `OR` conditions for the Where expression in a way that can be handled by Realm BUT is it worth it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think that's the route I'm going to have to take for the time being. Is it worth it, debatable, especially since it looks like the 10.2 release may provide the missing functionality. But so far, the beta releases for that have been to buggy to use. I'm currently porting over a .NET app from LiteDb to Realm simply because my past experience has shown Realm performance to be pretty darn good compared to any other local db stack. So I can't really deploy with a beta version of a library -- which gets to the 'is it worth it?' question.

Answer (score 1):

Docs say you need to use [Filter](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/5e8efd12cc502bb981bd7938183e74cea1844ad3/Realm/Realm/Extensions/CollectionExtensions.cs#L287) when you encounter a `NotSupportedException`. Read the comments on the method for a link to the `NSPredicate` cheat sheet, there is quite a lot you can do with it :)

Comment: So you're saying I can use the NSPredicate syntax in C#?

Comment: Yes, I pulled that from the Realm .NET github. If it doesn’t work then we need to raise an issue with them

Comment: Have a look at one of their unit tests [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/903b4d0b304f887e37e2d905384fb572a6496e70/Tests/Realm.Tests/Database/RealmValueTests.cs#L1000)

Comment: So the filter method seems to work as long as I have a constant expression that I can use. Realm has always supported substitution variables in their predicate queries, and even the unit test you pointed shows as much, but in my IDE it's only showing a Filter() method that takes a single argument (the predicate string).

Comment: Current release: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/10.1.4/Realm/Realm/Extensions/CollectionExtensions.cs

Comment: I see there are some beta version on nuget, try install one of those and see if you come right

Comment: Also, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038857/1901309) and see if that helps

Comment: I believe this may be the route I have to take.

Answer (score 1):

Update to question. First and foremost, thank you to all who participated and help point me in the right direction. The final answer ended up being a combination of a couple of things, but in short it was this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009005/query-realm-for-objects-by-ids-collection/54038857#54038857) that ended up solving the issue.

The current version of Realm has support for Mongo ObjectId, however, using ObjectId in the Filter() method didn't really work. So the fix was to end up using a string as the PK but use ObjectId in the DTO -- converting to ObjectId on the way out, and ToString() on the way into Realm.

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions {
    public static IQueryable<T> In<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, IList<ObjectId> objList)
        where T : RealmObject {
        var query = string.Join(" OR ", objList.Select(i => $"{propertyName} == '{i.ToString()}'"));
        var results = source.Filter(query);

        return results;
    }
}
```

My code utilizing the extension

```
public Task DeleteEvents(List<ObjectId> ids) {
        return Task.Run(() => {
            using (var realm = GetRealm())
            {
                using (var transaction = realm.BeginWrite())
                {
                    try {
                        // In order to support this with the current version of Realm we had to write an extension In()
                        // that explodes the list into a Filter() expression of OR comparisons. This also required us
                        // to use string as the underlying PK type instead of ObjectId. In this way, our domain object
                        // still expects ObjectId, so we ToString() on the way into realm and ObjectId.Parse() on the
                        // way out to our DTO.
                        var results = realm.All<DeviceEventEntity>().In("Id", ids);
                        realm.RemoveRange(results);
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw new ServiceException("Unable to delete events. Transaction has been rolled back.", exception);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This version works with guid properties

```
 public static IQueryable<T> In<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, IEnumerable<Guid?> objList)
        where T : IRealmObject
    {
        int count = 0;
        var query = string.Concat("Id in { $", string.Join(", $", objList.Select(i => count++)), "}");
        var results = source.Filter<T>(query, objList.Select(x=> (QueryArgument)x).ToArray());
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**.